# AudioKit Cookbook v.5 build fails (xcode 13.2.1)

Tags: c++, swift, audiokit, cookbook

I have been trying to build, to no avail, the Cookbook under Xcode 13.2.1. I get "Analyze Failed" with the following errors:

**Stk**:

Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Semantic issues (20):
(some of the error messages appear with varying array sizes, I quote only one for brevity):

- No template named num_get (istream)
- No template named bitset (istream)
- Implicit instantiation of undefined template std::ostream (sstream, istream)
- Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostringstream' (aka 'basic_ostringstream') and 'const char [60]') (instrmnt.h, Filter.h, Whistle.cpp)
- Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'char') (Stk.h)

**Cookbook Project**:
5 semantic issues similar to those above

**AudioKit**: Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Any suggestions to get this going? I am at a complete loss. I am targeting iOS 15.  I'll be happy to provide additional information, if needed.

For reference here are the versions of the Cookbook and dependencies that I'm using:

- Cookbook (?, 5/2/2022 commit)
- AudioKit 5.4.1
- AudioKitEx 5.4.0
- AudioKitUI (?, 5/3/22 commit)
- DunneAudioKit 5.4.1
- KissFFT 1.0.0
- SoundpipeAudioKit 4.4.1
- SporthAudioKIt 5.3.1
- STKAudioKit 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Does it look like all the Swift Packages were loaded properly? I'm on that same Xcode version so it should be working. Here are a few things to try:

• Select File > Packages > Resolve Package Version

• Delete the app from your device/simulator if you ran it previously on another Cookbook version

• Restart Xcode and select Product > Clean Build Folder

Comment: Suggestion 2 does not really apply: never managed to build this or any other version. The other two, tried, with no success. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Would you mind detailing the version number of the Cookbook you succeeded in building, as well as the number versions of the dependencies used in the build? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm on the latest version on the Main branch with AK 5.4.1, AKEX 5.4.0, AKUI main, DAK 5.4.1, KissFFT 1.0.0, SPAK 5.4.0, SPAK 5.4.0, SAK 5.3.1, STKAK 5.3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems to me that the problems actually come from the C++ headers used by the compiler, rather than AK itself. A new commit of the Cookbook was posted today, but I'm still facing the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

A fresh install of Xcode did the trick. Go figure. Thanks everyone for your suggestions and information.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened the second time. I was working on a pure C++ command line project in Xcode 14.1 and suddenly couldn't build it anymore. I couldn't build anything if it had `#include <iostream>` line.

Reinstalling Xcode fixed this problem. Thanks for the tip! Here is what I did eventually:

- Deleted `Xcode 14.1` from `/Applications`
- Deleted `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
- Deleted `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
- Rebooted
- Reinstalled Xcode from `.xip` archive and reinstalled `CommandLineTools for Xcode 14.1` from `.pkg`